# ExtJS 3.4 with Extensible Calendar - Multiple day events are shown as full day events

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar

I use ExtJS 3.4 with the extensible calendar compatible with my version of extjs, but I've seen that the same problem is for the latest calendar also : http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/basic.html .

What do I mean exactly: I create a 3 day event (from today at 3 pm until 1 day after tomorrow at 5 pm) - the event is shown as a full day event in week view. And this is somehow incorrect. I want it to be shown shaded from 3 pm today until 1 day after tomorrow at 5 pm... Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I understand that it was too long ago. But have you solved the problem? I just looking for the solution of it too